# How do I calculate the sine integral for a specific input?

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I need to solve an equation containing the Sine Integral $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{2 k \pi}{x}\right)$ in mathjs which doesn't have the $\mathrm{Si}$ function. Is there another way to represent this?

If $$
\mathrm{Si}\left(z\right) = \int_{0}^{z}{\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t}
$$

How do I actually calculate $\mathrm{Si}\left(…\right)$. It seems like I have to find a way to integrate $z$ every time I see $\mathrm{Si}\left(z\right)$ but calculators and computers wouldn't do that if $\mathrm{Si}\left(z\right)$ is a known function?

See : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E2%281+%2F+x%29

Comment: The "function" you defined is not sine integral. It is a constant equal to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Oops, thanks, I corrected the Sine Integral function. Wolfram Alpha uses $Si$ as the sine integral. How do I calculate it when I don't have a $Si$ function available to me, as in mathjs?

Comment: What is the equation you want to solve?

Comment: I just wanted to know what the integral of $sin(1/x)$ looked like, then $Si$ popped up. I have since found out that $Si$ involves the Taylor series, so computers estimate rather than calculate it.

Comment: This is why it is a *special function*.

Comment: This function is really tricky to compute. The best practical method I have found is to use the a combination of Taylor's series (for small x) and the Asymptotic series (for large x). See the code at https://pastebin.com/TeTjxN9q for example. The formulas in Wikipedia page was used. For continued fraction formula, see "Fresnel Integrals, Cosine and Sine Integrals", by Press and Teukolsky, 1992.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Si}(x)  
&= 
\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}t  dt
,
\end{align}$$ for $0\leq x \leq \pi$, you could use the magnificent approximation
 $$\sin(t) \sim \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad (0\leq t\leq\pi)$$  proposed, more than $\color{red}{1400}$ years ado by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

If you think about it, it is a kind of Padé approximant.

As a result, this will give the simple
$$\operatorname{Si}(x)\sim  -2 \left(\log \left(\frac{4 x^2}{5 \pi ^2}-\frac{4 x}{5 \pi }+1\right)+\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 x}{2 x-5 \pi }\right)\right) $$ which shows a maximum absolute error of $0.00367$ and  a maximum relative error of $1.86$%.

Much better would be the $[7,6]$ Padé approximant which I shall write as
$$\operatorname{Si}(x)\sim x \,\frac{1+\sum _{i=1}^3 a_i\,x^{2 i}  } {1+\sum _{i=1}^3b_i\,x^{2 i}  }$$
 where the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are respectively
$$\left\{-\frac{13524601565}{379956015036},\frac{567252710471}{766244630322600},-
   \frac{35803984658017}{8109933167334398400}\right\}$$
$$\left\{\frac{842673993}{42217335004},\frac{1864994705}{10216595070968},\frac{532
   2538193}{6620353605987264}\right\}$$ which gives a maximum absolute error of $5.21 \times 10^{-7}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you [answered yourself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644784/how-do-i-calculate-the-sine-integral-for-a-specific-input/3644993#3644993), the sine integral can computed efficiently using [Pade approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) - a common tool in numerical analysis.

If you've got a decent numerical integrator, then you can compute it directly from the definition as well. The focus of the [MathJS Javascript library](https://mathjs.org/) that you refer to, though, is not really numeric computation but basic symbolic representation.  I recommend that you check out the [adaptive Simpson integrator](https://github.com/scijs/integrate-adaptive-simpson) from the [SciJS](https://github.com/scijs/) library.

Here's [an implementation](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/the-sine-integral)  of the Sine Integral [on Observable](https://observablehq.com/) that I used to generate the following plot:

[image]

Note that it agrees quite well with [WolframAlpha's plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Si%28x%29%2C+x%3D-30..30).

Comment: wow, thanks, I'll start using the SciJS library. I've been checking out ObservableHG as well, great stuff. I need arbitrary precision so would probably have to do some trickery with $e^{i\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

Computers estimate $Si$ rather than calculate it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Efficient_evaluation